# Crear emoticonos personalizados

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

Buenas querria saber si es posible convertir una imagen en un emoticono para una aplicacion android. He probado con EmojiCompat etc pero lo unico que consigo es que me salga este mensaje
**android.graphics.Bitmap@13a72d1**

O la imagen salia en texto pero no era un emoticono.

Entonces me pregunté si seria posible realizar esto, o el realizar emoticonos, ojo emoticonos no stickers, solo es posible que lo haga google WhatsApp o quien sea que se encargue de hacerlos. Gracias

Comment: Agrega por favor como tratas de realizarlo, es importante.